# DPI changes of WinForm in C#

Tags: c#, resolution, dpi

I have developed an application that controls couple of maxon motors in C#. My OS is Win 8.1. My program works properly. However, it has one strange behavior. When I press a specific button, the dpi (resolution) of the main form of the application highly increases and the size of the window decreases. So before pressing this button I have a windows with same dpi of other windows, and after pressing this button, I have a high resolution/small windows. I figured it out that the piece of code making this happened is:

```
Device.Init();
```

which is related to one of the maxon dlls. Does anyone know how I can remove this effect? Is there anyway to set resolution in Visual Studio?

Comment: That's a pretty magic button.  You'd better take care of it [up front](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034).

Comment: I copy/paste -ed what suggested in that link with no luck. Any other solution?

Comment: Of course, get in touch with the wizard from "maxon".  Pick up the phone.